# Android: Error in parsing string from string.xml

Tags: android, layout, textview, string.xml

I have specified the string value as in  String.xml

```
<string name="complaint_fragment_type_label">Type</string>
```

and in layout file as

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/complaint_fragment_type_label"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

but i am having errors in getting the string "Type" in the TextView. what may be the solution to get the string in the textview?

Comment: `but i am having errors in getting the string "Type" in the TextView. ` What is the errors?!!

Comment: there is no error in your code..what error you are getting

Comment: show the logcat

Comment: Have you tested on real device? It seems you are seeing in xml file

Comment: I have tested your code its working fine.please post your error log

Comment: As you have define the "Type" value for key complaint_fragment_type_label so you will see the Type on TextView if you want some other value then replace Type with that one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because string.xml is not values resource file. You can create values resource file by right clicking on values directory then selecting new there you will get the option. Then just name it as **string** and give `<string>` tag inside the `<resources>` tag and you are done

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Complaint"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Try this...